# Long double float in C supported?

Tags: c

The output of following code piece is 0.000000. Please tell me why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
printf("%f\n",123.456789l);
}
```

I am using GCC 4.9 in Linux (Debian 8.3).

Comment: @HansPassant: I want to have long double. The output without the L is normal.

Comment: Explain in your own words what you think %f means.

Comment: Why have such a statement, unless you want to know how many significant figures are printed with unqualified   **%f**  when a loop would be better ?

Comment: Incorrect format specifier for long double.

Comment: Just preprocess this file #include <float.h> LDBL_MAX and you see 1.18973149535723176502e+4932L which answers your question.              – Marc Glisse Feb 4 '14 at 16:27

Comment: Use  **%lf** for the format specifier.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was thinking it was for all float literals (single precision, double precision, and long double 80bit precision), but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printf's `%f` format expects a plain double.  For long double you need `%Lf`.  (And that's a capital L.)

It's hard to say exactly why you got 0.000, but when you pass one type (long double) to a format specifier that expects something else (`%f`, plain double), you almost never get what you want.

This is one thing newer compilers can be really helpful about.  When I tried your code, my copy of gcc (4.6.3) was as silent as yours, but clang said "warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'long double'", and I'm pretty sure newer versions of gcc would complain, too.